# Possible to make flask login system which doesn't use client-side session/cookie?

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-login

I'm working on a Flask app to be used by a medical client. Their IT dept is so up tight about security that they disable cookies and scripting network-wide.

Luckly, wtf-forms was able to address one of these issues with server-side validation of form input.

However, I'm getting hung up on the login system. I've implemented flask-login, but this apparently requires client-side data as I'm unable to log in when testing in a browser with these features disabled.

Is there any way to create a login with zero client-side data?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? Would love to hear detail about it as I'm also facing same problem where it could not pass the login screen and kept looping it...

Comment: @Jignesh I did not end up finishing this project as it was abandoned :(

Answer (score 3):

You can of course do it without cookies. You just have to get the auth on every request.

Here is an [example in flask using only Basic HTTP Auth](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/). If you are not using 100% of the time HTTPS, then you should use [Digest Auth](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/31/) which is secure.

**Update**: All links are broken. :(

Just use Flask-HTTPAuth which implements Basic Auth and others: https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

From the website:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

users = {
    "john": generate_password_hash("hello"),
    "susan": generate_password_hash("bye")
}

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    # Or access the DB.
    if username in users check_password_hash(users.get(username), password):
        return username

@app.route('/')
@auth.login_required
def index():
    return "Hello, {}!".format(auth.current_user())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: the example is a 404 now. It's usually good to explain the gist of the idea in the answer itself instead of just linking to an answer

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, which reminds me back to the good-old-days in PHP using `trans-sid`, would be to pass the session_id in the url and store the session on the backend to prevent the url parameters from getting to large (in case of large session stores).

You can implement this using a combination of the `@app.url_defaults` and `@app.url_value_preprocessor` signals, also known as [Flask's URL preprocessors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/urlprocessors/).

This depends on your correct use of url_for, because that's where the session id will get appended. Let's do a short proof-of-concept:

```
@app.url_defaults
def add_session_id(endpoint, values):
    if 'session_id' in values:
        # Allows to manually override the session_id, might not be wanted.
        return
    if g.session_id:
        values['session_id'] = g.session_id

@app.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_session_id(endpoint, values):
    g.session_id = values.pop('session_id', None)
```

Now, all you need to do is store the session somewhere useful (using for example a DB, or [Redis](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/), and set the session_id using `g.session_id = session_id_here`.

On each subsequent request, g.session_id should be the same session id, because `url_for` should append `?session_id=yoursessionid` to the url. Your authentication should check for the existence of `g.session_id` and act accordingly.

*Note that if your session stays small, you could probably store the whole session in the url parameter instead of an id.*

Answer (score 1):

With such restrictions as not having zero client side data, you could pass a session token in the GET parameters of every link rendered in the html page.

Or you could create only POST views with a hidden token input (may be more secure indeed).

Comment: Then every time some copied/pasted a link, any user clicking on that link would (necessarily) gain access to the account of the user who copied it.  This is non-security masquerading as security.

Comment: You could tie a token to an ip, or you could do everything in POST.

Comment: DHCP makes that basically impossible.  A wandering client on a wireless network would get booted every time they moved their lap top.

Comment: As said above, you could architect all your site in POST. As for the DHCP, I think the restrictions the OP is facing are due to some private company network were computers may be wired to the network with a fixed IP. So it depends on the situation.

Comment: OP said his client is a security conscious medical client, nothing else.  While it's possible they're only using wired terminals, it's just as possible that they have controlled company laptops, tablets etc.

Comment: And architecting the whole site in POST is terrible architecture.  You're better off convincing the client to whitelist your hostname and only connecting via SSL.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but ASP.NET Web Forms is all about forms everywhere on your webpages. And it's a technology that has been widely used, while I agree it's terrible.

Comment: Definitely POST and not GET. That is the way that Web Forms works (everything is a POST and it's all posting state back to itself) - it is pretty terrible, but if you can't use scripting and you can't use cookies, that's the only way I know of to preserve state is to pass the token back and forth via a hidden input and a form (the only thing then is that you cannot have any links - everything has to be a button because everything has to submit the form to preserve the state [although you can *style* buttons to look like links])

Comment: HTTP Basic Auth will also give you authentication and so is the other option in this environment.

Answer (score -2):

Nope.  That's literally impossible over pure HTTP.  HTTP is a stateless protocol, which means that in order to preserve state, the client has to be able to identify itself on every request.

What you *might* be able to do is HTTP Basic Authentication over HTTPS, then access that Authentication on the server side.

Comment: They may be work arounds, like passing a token in the http html responses.

Comment: You could pass a session in the GET parameters, but that's exactly as secure as simply making all your resources public.

Comment: Well not quite, or explain why it would be less secure please.

Comment: It's simply not secure at all.  It provides no protection to an account, and makes it super easy to accidentally provide an attacker with access to your account.